# sudo yum remove pythonを誤ってしたのですが、もとに戻し方が分かりません

Tags: python, linux, centos

centos で、`sudo yum remove python`を実行してしまいました。
centosの一部の機能が使えない状態になりました。
`sudo yum install python`を実行してもcentosの一部の機能が使えないです。
どうすれば、もとの状態に戻すことができるのでしょうか

---

追記
CentOSのバージョンは、
`CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`

恐らく、ライブラリーではなく、依存パッケージも削除してしまった状態だと思います。
`sudo yum remove python`を実行すると、大量に削除されました。

---

追記
`sudo rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs *.rpm`を実行しますと、

```
エラー: 依存性の欠如:
    python-rpm-macros > 3-30 は python-devel-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64 に必要とされています
    python2-rpm-macros > 3-30 は python-devel-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64 に必要とされています
```

と出力されました。

Comment: 削除されたのは Python パッケージ単体ですか？それとも依存パッケージも削除してしまった状態ですか？ 恐らく yum コマンドも削除されている可能性があります。 / CentOS の詳細なバージョン情報 (例: `7.9.2009`) も記載してください。

Answer (score 1):

以下は [Reinstalling python on CentOS to be able to use yum - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/410075) での [回答の一つ](https://serverfault.com/a/611048) を参考にしたもので、私自身が実際に試したものではない点はご了承ください。

---

CentOS において Python は OS の動作に関わるパッケージなので、削除時に依存パッケージとして yum コマンド等も削除されている可能性があります。

まずは以下の手順で必要最低限なパッケージの再インストールを試してみてください。

```
### 作業用のディレクトリに移動
$ cd /tmp

### 必要なパッケージファイルをダウンロード
$ wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-168.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
$ wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64.rpm
$ wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/python-devel-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64.rpm
$ wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/python-libs-2.7.5-89.el7.x86_64.rpm

### rpm コマンドでパッケージをインストール
$ sudo rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs *.rpm
```

また、yum コマンドでのパッケージ操作のログが `/var/log/yum.log*` に記録されている可能性があるので、誤って削除したパッケージを確認する際のヒントになるかもしれません。

```
$ sudo less /var/log/yum.log
```

##### 追記

rpm コマンド実行時に足りないパッケージが表示されるようであれば、[ミラーサイトのディレクトリ](http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/) から都度パッケージを確認してダウンロードしてください。

```
$ wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/python-rpm-macros-3-34.el7.noarch.rpm
$ wget http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/python2-rpm-macros-3-34.el7.noarch.rpm
```